# Why is my Semigroup/Monoid instance overlapping?

Tags: haskell, typeclass, monoids

I'm trying to implement a way to lazily construct nondeterministic finite automata (NFAs). I did this [years ago](https://github.com/bert2/nfa-string-matching/blob/master/StringMatcher/ProtoAutom.fs) in F# and now want to try it with Haskell while leveraging the `Monoid` typeclass.

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE TypeSynonymInstances, FlexibleInstances #-}

module NFA where

data State = State Match State | Split State State | Final deriving (Show)
data Match = Any | Char Char | ... deriving (Show)

type StateF = State -> State

complete :: StateF -> State -> State
complete statef exit = statef exit

connect :: StateF -> StateF -> StateF
connect fst snd = complete fst . complete snd

empty :: StateF
empty = id

instance Semigroup StateF where
  (<>) = connect

instance Monoid StateF where
  mempty = empty
```

This code doesn't compile, because my `Semigroup` and `Monoid` instances are overlapping with `instance Semigroup b => Semigroup (a -> b)` and `instance Monoid b => Monoid (a -> b)` from `GHC.Base`, but I don't understand why.

I see that there is a `Monoid` instance on functions `a -> b`, where `b` is a `Monoid` itself. But `State` doesn't have a `Monoid` instance, so how can `StateF` (`State -> State`) overlap?

Is it because someone *might* implement `Monoid` for `State` elsewhere?

Also, how can I fix this?

I'm aware that a could just define `StateF` as...

```hs
data StateF = StateF (State -> State)
```

...but that would also increase syntax noise when pattern matching and constructing `StateF`s.

The comiler errors:

```
src\NFA.hs:10:10: error:
    * Overlapping instances for Semigroup StateF
        arising from a use of `GHC.Base.$dmsconcat'
      Matching instances:
        instance Semigroup b => Semigroup (a -> b) -- Defined in `GHC.Base'
        instance Semigroup StateF -- Defined at src\NFA.hs:10:10
    * In the expression: GHC.Base.$dmsconcat @(StateF)
      In an equation for `GHC.Base.sconcat':
          GHC.Base.sconcat = GHC.Base.$dmsconcat @(StateF)
      In the instance declaration for `Semigroup StateF'
   |
10 | instance Semigroup StateF where
   |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

src\NFA.hs:10:10: error:
    * Overlapping instances for Semigroup StateF
        arising from a use of `GHC.Base.$dmstimes'
      Matching instances:
        instance Semigroup b => Semigroup (a -> b) -- Defined in `GHC.Base'
        instance Semigroup StateF -- Defined at src\NFA.hs:10:10
    * In the expression: GHC.Base.$dmstimes @(StateF)
      In an equation for `GHC.Base.stimes':
          GHC.Base.stimes = GHC.Base.$dmstimes @(StateF)
      In the instance declaration for `Semigroup StateF'
   |
10 | instance Semigroup StateF where
   |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

src\NFA.hs:13:10: error:
    * Overlapping instances for Semigroup StateF
        arising from the superclasses of an instance declaration
      Matching instances:
        instance Semigroup b => Semigroup (a -> b) -- Defined in `GHC.Base'
        instance Semigroup StateF -- Defined at src\NFA.hs:10:10
    * In the instance declaration for `Monoid StateF'
   |
13 | instance Monoid StateF where
   |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^

src\NFA.hs:13:10: error:
    * Overlapping instances for Monoid StateF
        arising from a use of `GHC.Base.$dmmappend'
      Matching instances:
        instance Monoid b => Monoid (a -> b) -- Defined in `GHC.Base'
        instance Monoid StateF -- Defined at src\NFA.hs:13:10
    * In the expression: GHC.Base.$dmmappend @(StateF)
      In an equation for `mappend':
          mappend = GHC.Base.$dmmappend @(StateF)
      In the instance declaration for `Monoid StateF'
   |
13 | instance Monoid StateF where
   |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^

src\NFA.hs:13:10: error:
    * Overlapping instances for Monoid StateF
        arising from a use of `GHC.Base.$dmmconcat'
      Matching instances:
        instance Monoid b => Monoid (a -> b) -- Defined in `GHC.Base'
        instance Monoid StateF -- Defined at src\NFA.hs:13:10
    * In the expression: GHC.Base.$dmmconcat @(StateF)
      In an equation for `mconcat':
          mconcat = GHC.Base.$dmmconcat @(StateF)
      In the instance declaration for `Monoid StateF'
   |
13 | instance Monoid StateF where
   |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: You can (and arguably should) define `StateF` as a `newtype`, not just a type alias. Your code will be a little more verbose, but there's no runtime overhead like the same definition with `data`.

Comment: Just to be super clear: it's overlapping because functions already have a `Monoid` instance, and your `StateF` is just an alias for one specific function type.

Comment: @Carl but the existing instance isn't just for any kind of function, it's specifically for functions that return an instance of `Monoid`. Or am I misunderstanding the signature `Monoid b => Monoid (a -> b)`?

Comment: It turns out that an `instance Monoid b => Monoid (a -> b)` does not define a conditional instance that applies only when `b` is a `Monoid`.  It defines an unconditional `Monoid` instance for all `a -> b` that, when used, will introduce a requirement for a `Monoid b` instance.  That is, constraints in instance definitions play no role in instance selection; they are only consulted after the instance is selected.

Comment: This `Monoid` exists in the standard library, by the way, as [`Endo State`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html#t:Endo).

Comment: You can derive the instance via that type. `newtype StateF = .. deriving (Semigroup, Monoid) via Endo State`

Comment: You ask "Is it because someone might implement Monoid for State elsewhere?". The answer is, that's one of the reasons. The default typelcass rules enforce a useful invariant: if a program compiles successfully, then adding any typeclass instance to any type shouldn't change how the program behaves.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At least for the code shown, changing `StateF` from a type alias to a `newtype` introduces minimal changes and no runtime overhead.

```
module NFA where

data State = State Match State | Split State State | Final deriving (Show)
data Match = Any | Char Char | ... deriving (Show)

newtype StateF = StateF (State -> State)

-- This is one change
complete :: StateF -> State -> State
complete (StateF f) = f

-- This is another
connect :: StateF -> StateF -> StateF
connect fst snd = StateF $ complete fst . complete snd

-- This is a third
empty :: StateF
empty = StateF id

instance Semigroup StateF where
  (<>) = connect

instance Monoid StateF where
  mempty = empty
```

If you use record syntax, you won't even need pattern-matching for `complete`:

```
newtype StateF  = StateF { runStateF :: State -> State }

complete :: StateF -> State -> State
-- complete statef exit = runStateF statef exit
-- complete statef = runStateF statef
complete = runStateF
```

(Don't think of `complete` as actually *applying* the state transformer to a state, but rather *extracting* the state transformer so that it *can* be applied to a state.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It sill bugs me a bit that I have to use the `StateF` ctor everywhere, but that's probably due to my unfamiliarity with haskell's conventions and best practices. I updated my question with a solution I pieced together from your answer and other comments.

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride To mitigate the need of wrapping / unwrapping newtype ctors, we now have `Data.Coerce.coerce`, which should allow `connect = coerce (.)`. Still, I'd recommend you first learn how to do the (un)wrapping manually before trying automagic tools. Debugging the automagic stuff when it does not work as expected can be tricky if you don't understand what's going on under the hood.

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride Using `StateF` everywhere is extra noise, but it can also be extra safety; if a `StateF` is a particular concept to you, rather than any function that merely *happens* to have type `State -> State` then I think making it a separate type is likely a good thing (makes the typechecker aware of it as a separate concept, so it will prevent you from mixing them up). For example, a "query" function that inspected a `State` and returned a `State` could easily (maybe after partial application) end up as a `State -> State`, which would also be a `StateF` by your original definition.

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride OTOH if a `StateF` is really and truly nothing more than a shorthand for a `State -> State`, and you're happy for any given function with that type to function as a `StateF`, then I would probably stick with the type alias and just avoid the monoid/semigroup instance (using new standalone operators instead). In that case a `StateF` isn't a "thing" in its own right, just a function, and it would be potentially confusing to use nonstandard instances for them even if you could avoid the builtin ones. Either option makes sense, depending on how you want to think of `StateF`.